# copy static files to build output folder in gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I was using ANT before (Android Project) and i had "static" files in the same packages as my code

Here is an example

> src/com/my/app/test/Parser.java
>
> src/com/my/app/test/json_to_parse.json

When executing the unit tests, the json file was copied into the gen folder, therfor it was possible to access the json in the test with

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)`

I had to convert the project to gradle, but now the tests are failing.
After checking the "build" folder, i've realised, the .json files are not there, therefor the getResourceAsStream method returns null.

Any idea how to include these "static" files (json, xml, ...) into the build folder?

Comment: Why don't you place the files under `src/test/resources`?

Comment: This is what i'm going to to actually. But even this does not work straight out of the box in Android Studio (in AS 1.1, it's rumored it will be fixed in 1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you are asking about are called "resource files" in Maven/Gradle lingo.

Gradle assumes that you are using the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

So, either you move your files into `src/test/resources` (then Gradle will pick them up automatically), or you tell Gradle that it should look for resources in some other place.

In the latter case, you need to [modify the processTestResources task.](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) However, keeping resource files in the same directory as source code is a bad practice. So I advise the former option.

Comment: Actually you gave the right answer, so i'll mark this one as correct. But because my case was quite specific (and is actually an issue of Android Studio <= 1.1 not gradle itself) i've added another answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: First link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

Moving the files into the resources folder did not work out of the box in Android Studio (even though is should have)

This should be fixed in Android Studio 1.2.
However, this is what i did:

Moved all static files into the resources folder.

In my unit-test module i've added this to the build.gradle file

```
task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
    from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
    into "${buildDir}/classes/test"
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

Now, all files located inside src/test/resources will be copied into /classes/test where i can access them with

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

If i keep the package structure inside the resources folder the same as it was in the java folder, i don't need to adjust any code.

To complete the story a bit more:

JUnit4 runner requires

`getClass().getResourceAsStream(name)`

while Robolectric requires

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)`

Comment: This still returns a null and not a file. any ideas? I'm using robolectric 3, AS 1.3, gradle 1.2.2

Comment: Seems to still be an issue when using a java module which specifies the resources using     sourceSets { test { resources { ***    . This is as of android studio 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is happen when you create apk with AndroidStudio.

you can create a jar file that includes your resources with jar.exe

for example i put a.txt into resources directory
and run this code in cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\jar" cvfe res.jar -c resources
```

after that a jar file "res.jar" was created
then add that res.jar into libs folder in your project
when your apk is creating resources are added to your final apk and you can use this code to acsess a.txt:

```
someclass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/a.txt");
```

with this job no need to change Gradle setting.